# Splash "Default.png" on launch image for 2 differents targets in iphone app

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have 2 versions of my app, and I can't specify launch image for the lite because when I put the image of the full version it suddenly changes my lite image.

An alert appear and tells me if I want to replace 'Default.png':

```
    but the launch image must have the name "Default.png".
The file will be copied and added to your project as "Default.png". 
Do you want to continue?
```

can someone help me?

Answer (score 4):

An app can only have one Default.png. There's no way to programmatically or otherwise conditionally show different Default.png during launch of the same app.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm following you correctly you could create a Default.png that is entirely black and then display a png once Cocos2D initializes that will vary to whatever restrictions you choose.  I wouldn't recommend this as good practice and Apple certainly may reject an app/game submitted with a completely black Default.png but maybe not.  I've never tried something like that.

Comment: They did not for one of my apps. Make that 2 (the lite version). The app starts on a 'short' fade in-and-out of corporate logo (on black background) ... another nono in appStore dogma.

Comment: good one! I suppose as long as the black screen doesn't last for very long (2-3 secs max) it ought to be ok.

Comment: I made that method, it works for now; but I will try to put set something to make both png images appear. I don't understand why in the Lite version of iPad appears both splash, and in Iphone don't...